# how to show my csv file and edit it in gridview WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a simple csv reader that I wrote, it receives data in the format List<string[]> . I need to show this data in wpf and edit it. I use mvvm. If I write just like that, it won't do anything.

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Table}"> </DataGrid>
```

How can I do this? Is it possible for me to somehow output and edit data in a convenient format in the form of List<string[]>. A csv table can have an arbitrary number of columns, so I can't make any particular class inside the code. I tried to find an answer to this question on the Internet, looked at several similar projects, but something never figured it out.

Let's say I get the data this way

```
var _fileName = @"F:\test.csv";

CsvWriter reader = new CsvWriter(_fileName);

foreach(var item in reader.Read())
{
     Table.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: a two way binding is able to update data as you edit in control. but often you need some validations, so either find some existing thirdparty controls or more complex logic required.

Comment: A TwoWay Binding can not replace a string in a collection. You need to have a list of data items with a string property. Besides that, it is unclear what Table is and how it is connected to the view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a library called [CSVReader](https://www.stellman-greene.com/CSVReader/).
It converts any csv files to DataTables

Example:

```cs
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void OpenCSVButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {   
            DataTable dt = LoadCSVFileFromPath();
            dataGrid.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;

            //Simple method to convert DataTable to a List of strings
            AddToList(dt);
        }

        private List<string> AddToList(DataTable table)
        {
            List<string> strTable = new List<string>();
            foreach(DataRow rows in table.Rows)
            {
                foreach (DataColumn cols in table.Columns)
                    strTable.Add(rows[cols].ToString());
            }

            return strTable;
        }

        private DataTable LoadCSVFileFromPath()
        {
            //Use this method to convert your CSV file to DataTable
            DataTable table = CSVReader.ReadCSVFile("FILEPATHGOESHERE", true);
            return table;
        }
    }
```

You can play around and achieve this in MVVM by binding the `DefaultView` of the `DataTable table` to `DataGrid`

Answer (score -2):

Dont use Binding.

XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid1" AutoGenerateColumns="True" />
```

Read the CSV data and conver it to DataTable, and place it into ItemsSource:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{ 
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LoadData();
    }

    DataTable GetDataTable(CsvReader csv)
    {
        var dt = new DataTable();

        csv.Read();
        csv.ReadHeader();
        foreach (var header in csv.HeaderRecord)
            dt.Columns.Add(header);

        var cols = dt.Columns.Count;
        while (csv.Read())
        {
            var row = dt.NewRow();

            for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++)
                row[i] = csv[i];

            dt.Rows.Add(row);
        }

        return dt;
    }

    DataTable table;
    string _fileName = @"F:\test.csv";
    void LoadData()
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(_fileName ))
        using (var csvReader = new CsvReader(reader, new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) { Delimiter = "," }))
        {
            table = GetDataTable(csvReader);
            table.AcceptChanges();
            dataGrid1.ItemsSource = table.AsDataView();
        }
    }

    void SaveData()
    {
        if (table.GetChanges() != null)
        {
            //write DataTable to csv...
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Why should he not bind?

Comment: @enesimam I meant that there is no need, it is not necessary to get the desired result.